# jQuery Cycle pager animations / transitions

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

Is there a way to have transitions for the pagers using the jQuery cycle plugin? Right now it just adds a class to the active pager. But that doesn't look very cool. It would be much better if it could fade out that class at the same time it fades in on the next pager. Or maybe if there could be an overlay that slides over the pagers.

I don't have any example code. But here's the link to the available options:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

I'm not very good at jQuery myself, so I hope one of you might have an idea if those options might be of any help.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just add some CSS transitions onto the pager stuff so that they fade between active and inactive states.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this options

```
animIn:  { opacity:1 }, animOut: { opacity:0 }
```

If you could past the cycle caaling line I could be more specific